# VBA makro to format XML in Excel to CSV

Tags: vba, excel

I need to reformat a XML file to .CSV.
I already opened the XML in Excel and did a little formating but now I really need to write a macro to get the data into shape. I already started bu I really have issues with the loop logic.

the List has a couple thousand Articles with a variable amount of subarticles.
each subarticle as a the same amount of properties but not every article has the same properties.

https://picload.org/image/ipialic/now.jpg

https://picload.org/image/ipialip/then.jpg

My Code up till now looks like this:

```
    Option Explicit
Dim rowCount As Long, articleCount As Long, propertyCount As Integer, name As String

Sub Sortfunction()
rowCount = 1
articleCount = 0
propertyCount = 0

Do While Sheets("Test").Cells(rowCount, 1).Value <> "end"

    If Cells(rowCount, 1).Value = "Reference" Then
        rowCount = rowCount + 1

        Do While Cells(rowCount, 3).Value = ""
            If Cells(rowCount, 3).Value = "4" Then

            End If
        articleCount = articleCount + 1
        Loop

        articleCount = articleCount + 1
    End If
rowCount = rowCount + 1
Loop

Sheets("result").Cells(1, 1).Value = rowCount
Sheets("result").Cells(2, 1).Value = articleCount

End Sub
```

At the end of the document i wrote the "end" to have a hook to stop the loop.

Can anyone provide some help? I'm really not the best programmer :-/
I'd really appreciate any help I can get :-)

Comment: You can post image by uploading to other free site and post the link in your answer. Do it. Your question is not clear. Is this code work? If not, tell which line give you error or issue.

Comment: I loaded 2 pictures up, the first shows the current situation, the second picture shows what the table should look like. The code does not word yet, it is roughly a start to a probably way more complex macro which I'm currently not able to write by myself :-( I don't want anybody to write the macro for me but I would be glad for any tips or stuff to look up to figure it out myself.

Comment: Let me confirm, this code give picture `now` and you need other suggestion for getting `then` picture.

Comment: I can confirm this :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here he's a translation into algorithm and some tips on functions

**update:** it was more tricky than I thought... I had to rewrite the code.
The main problem is "how to decide when change column".

I choose this solution "Each product in reference must have the same amount of properties".

If it's not the case, please indicate "how you decide when you have to create a new Column" (you can explain it in plain words)

Here the code rewrited. I tried it on your exemple, it work

```
Public Sub test()
    ' Set the range to navigate in your first sheet
    Dim cell As Range: Set cell = Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A1")

    ' set the range to navigate in your result sheet
    Dim res As Range: Set res = Nothing
    ' pos will be used to know the position of a product
    Dim lastProperties As Range, posProperties As Range

    ' While the cell value is not "end"
    Do While cell <> "end"

        ' if the cell is a reference
        If cell = "Reference" Then
            ' Set the range of res
            If res Is Nothing Then
                Set res = Sheets("Feuil2").Range("A1")
            Else
                Set res = Sheets("Feuil2").Range("A" & lastProperties.offset(2).Row)
            End If
            ' I set Offset(2) so you will have an empty line between 2 references

            ' Set the text of the new reference in the result
            res = cell.offset(, 1)    ' The reference is the cell 1 offset the right of the cell "Reference"
            ' WARNING : here no writing of titles anymore. It'll be done in the "Else".
            ' Here you just write "new reference" and reinit var
        Else
            ' Here we have a property
            ' If the property alreay exist, consider it a new product in the reference
            ' When we are on a new property, the column of the product if the next to the right
            If GetProperties(cell.offset(, 3), res, posProperties) Then
                Set lastProperties = posProperties
            End If

            posProperties = cell.offset(, 4)
        End If

        ' BIG FORGET: you have to get the next cell
        Set cell = cell.offset(1)
    Loop
End Sub
```

And the function to search / create your properties

```
Private Function GetProperties(ByVal propValues As String, ByVal start As Range, ByRef position As Range) As Boolean
    Set position = start.offset(1)

    ' Is the cell below the properties ? Return the row below
    ' Search for the first "empty row" on the line
    If position = propValues Then
        Do
            Set position = position.offset(, 1)
        Loop While Trim(position) <> ""

        ' Indicate it's an existing value
        GetProperties = True
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Is the range empty ?
    If Trim(position) = "" Then
        ' Create the new properties
        position = propValues
        Set position = position.offset(, 1)
        GetProperties = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Search the properties in the row below
    GetProperties = GetProperties(propValues, position, position)
End Function
```

It should do the work. If you have any question on understanding some part, don't hesitate

if you don't know about Offset, some reading : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx

Comment: This is actually pretty awesome so far and helped me a lot. the last big problem is that I don't know how many possible propertys there are. The file is about 80k lines long and as I said: most items have different properties :-/
 
While you were posting this I was already working on a similar approach (offset) but mine is by far not as great as yours ^^

Comment: Would it be possible to iterate through all of the porperties, store them in an array if they are not already in the array and fill the offsets you already gave me with the values in the array as long as array.length or somethin? Thats what I would do in JS at least...

The same would go for the select case....
sadly i have no idea how arrays in VBA work and the moment i try to create one i get an error :-D

Comment: You Sir made my day, week and probably even month! Million thanks to you!

Comment: Hm...no matter what i try it ends up looping forever after just printing the first reference :-/

Comment: I forget to reach the next line in the while loop.. I edit the macro, take a look at `' BIG FORGET: you have to get the next cell`. My mistake

Comment: Now it finishes it's work but it still has quite a few issues.

it seems to only create a single table for 1 reference, stuffs all the properties in it and messes things up quite badly. 

And seriously, no need to be sorry. You already taught me soooo much I don't even know how I could ever thank you enough!

Comment: I find a glitch in my code (it's a problem when I don't test a code..). The position of the new reference in the result sheet wasn't set. Take a look at `set res = iif(res is nothing`

Comment: https://picload.org/image/ipilaid/newnow.jpg

This is what it looks like right now. Looks quite amazing considering you are not even testing this ^^ Are you just doing this as a mindgame? 0.o

Article 1 should have all 5 properties, Article 2 Should have only properties 1-3 if that helps you somehow

Comment: Complete rewrite of the solution.. in the end, your problem is tricky.. The main problem is "when do you choose to change column in the result". If it don't work like you want, please describe in plain words "what is the algorithm to choose if it's a new column (a new product like "Dell" / "Apple" / "ATI")

Comment: I actually tried the following approach:

iterate the whole document ->if  Reference then copy the name to to results-> look for Subarticle->check how many properties (including the subarticle)the reference has by checking the how many rows are between 2 subarticles ->copy the property titles below the reference in the result page. ->check how many rows to next reference->divide by number of properties->copy items from the property value column in blocks equal to the divided amount to the result page till  all properties are transported.->look for next reference->repeat.

Comment: Sorry but i'm on week-end ;) I'll help you on monday

Comment: Sorry that I disturbed you on your well earned weekend :-)

Comment: Your approch is not bad, but i'm not convinced "how you decide it's a new product".. if it's "it's a new product since a property repeat", ok.
You can try to implement your solution, it should work. If you have problem with it, create a new answer, with the code, and explain where you have trouble with it

Comment: didn't you try the last solution I propose ? because it give what you want as result if each subproduct as the same amount of properties (but if you want to try it with your solution to learn, it's a good practice)

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't saw your last update and now it works like a charm. perfect solution! I can't vote you up enough ^^ A million thanks to you!